# Custom date field throwing DB constraint error "cannot be null"

Tags: civicase

I have a date field associated with a particular case type. When I try to create a new case, it is failing because the dates are empty. However, when I created the custom data, I did not make them required. There is one custom field that seems to work but it submits the empty field as '' (an empty string) as opposed to null.

Why is there a not null constraint on those fields, and ok to fix this by manually setting all those columns to allow null values?

We are using Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.7.4

Answer (score 1):

I guess that shouldn't be a problem in set the column to null in the DB because those are custom field

I did manage to do the same testing against lower version in 4.6.15 and mysql version 5.6.25 - Which works as excepted

I guess this may be a issue with mysql version or in the code so just check with the lower version or wait till the next release and if you have the same issue then please raise an issue

I guess this helps !!